# Can't edit .ini file because of read-only status

Tags: linux, eclipse, ini, manjaro

I've got a problem with editing eclipse.ini.
My system is Arch-based Manjaro, if it'll help.
I tried with edit it with a root rights with `sudo -e /snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini`, but it said "file system is for read only". Then I tried `sudo gedit /snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini`, and then it said "You're trying to save to save the file on a read-only disk". No system reboot is helped.
So what should I do? I'm trying to make my eclipse work for a few days already XD.

Comment: Why are you trying to edit it, and have you tried a download from download.eclipse.org instead?

Comment: I wanted to install eclipse on my Manjaro, so I searched in pamac, but found no eclipse there. So I googled "how to install eclipse on manjaro". The first link was to snapcraft io, so there I went. And your variant with eclipse.org was not even on second or third links in google results. I installed it with snap, and decided to start with hello world, but then I got "Launch error", and I gone search for solutions. One of the answers was that jdk/jre version discrepancy. I started to do everything I can, bcause after all I understand almost nothing about how does it work. After some time - this

Comment: And I just finished trying that case with eclipse.org - and yeah, it worked well, now I got my working Hello world application, thanks a lot. I just didn't know, that there is installing package on eclipse official site, my bad. I just started really enter programming world, and there are tons of unknown things to learn, I don't even know where is it right to start it all